# Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'FirstNameController' is not registered

Tags: angularjs

I created one sample application of Angular Js. It's working if I take only one controller. If I took tow controller then it's not working. It's showing **Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'FirstNameController' is not registered.** error. I referred [this site](https://www.guru99.com/angularjs-controller.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta chrset="UTF 8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Guru99 Global Event</h1>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="DemoApp">
 <div ng-controller="FirstNameController">

    First Name : <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>

    first Name: {{firstName}}
 </div>
<div ng-controller="LastNameController">
    Last name : <input type="text" ng-model="LastName"><br>
    Last Name: {{LastName}}
</div>
</div>
<script>
angular.module('DemoApp',[]).controller('FirstNameController', function($scope){
    $scope.firstName = "Anil";
});
angular.module('DemoApp',[]).controller('LastNameController', function($scope){
    $scope.LastName = "Jagtap";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're incorrectly declaring the `DemoApp` module twice. Chain the second controller definition instead, like so: `angular.module('DemoApp', []).controller('FirstNameController', ...).controller('LastNameController', ...)`.

Comment: @miqh, Thank you. It's working for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular.module("DemoApp") will create the module again.

So declare are

```
var module = Angular.module("DemoApp")


 module.controller('FirstNameController', function($scope){
    $scope.firstName = "Anil";
});

module.controller('lastNameController', function($scope){
    $scope.firstName = "Anil";
});
```